# J2ME HttpConnection getResponseCode() blocks waiting answer from server on Nokia N97

Tags: http, networking, java-me, nokia

I upload a file from a Nokia N97 phone to server, everything works fine but after file is uploaded I want to get response from server. The problem is that I get response only after half a minute or more. From what I see the code blocks in httpConnection.getResponseCode() waiting for response. I tested it on a Sony Ericsson and I get response very fast so I assume is a Nokia N97 problem. (is not a server problem because it works fine on other phones)

Does anyone knows why this thing happens only on Nokia?

Here is a code snippet:

public uploadFile() {

```
       httpConn = (HttpsConnection) Connector.open(url, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        ...
       //set httpConn parameters and request method 
       ...

       writeParametersAndFileName(os, "text/plain");


       **writeFileToStream(os);** 

       os.write("\r\n".getBytes());
       os.write("--".getBytes());

       os.write(boundary.getBytes());

       os.write("--".getBytes());
       os.write("\r\n".getBytes());

        *//here code blocks on Nokia N97. Same thing happens if I use os.flush() after
        // I send chunks of the file*
         .....
        codeResp = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        // check condition
        checkResponseHeader();
```

}

public **writeFileToStream()** {

```
        InputStream is = null;
        FileConnection c = null;
        try
        {
           c = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///"+ sourcePath, Connector.READ);

           if(c.exists()) {
               is = c.openInputStream();

               long fs = c.fileSize();
               while (total < fs) {
                    byte[] data = new byte[512];
                    int readAmount = is.read(data,0,512);                       
                    total += readAmount;
                    os.write(data, 0, readAmount);


            }

            //os.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
           //               
        }
        finally
        {
           //close connection

        }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only think your file has been uploaded.

Your call to getResponseCode() is the first one that causes the HttpConnection to actually connect to the server.

It won't return until it uploads the file, which presumably takes more than a minute.

This is perfectly valid behavior according to the HttpConnection specification in JSR-118:

"
 The following methods cause the transition to the Connected state when the connection is in Setup state.

```
* openInputStream
* openDataInputStream
* getLength
* getType
* getEncoding
* getHeaderField
* getResponseCode
* getResponseMessage
* getHeaderFieldInt
* getHeaderFieldDate
* getExpiration
* getDate
* getLastModified
* getHeaderField
* getHeaderFieldKey
```

"

I expect the other phones you have tried this on are less powerful than the N97 and need to flush the OutputStream, therefore connecting to the server before they should according to the specification.